# Aggregation of large (bilions of rows) datasets over PostgreSQL database

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, view, aggregate-functions

I'm struggling to find the right way how to aggregate large amounts of data.
Considering a database with average expextected incoming load of about 200 (500 peak) new rows per second, we wil reach one bilion rows within first three months. The expectation is to hold the data for at least 10years. Table will be pretty much static, no UPDATEs, no DELETEs, just INSERTs.
Is it real to expect the PostgreSQL server (with proper hardware and configuration) will manage such large amounts of data for querying or is it bad idea?

Now the requirment is that each customer will be able to generate aggregated reports for his transactions (could be tens or even hundreds of millions, depending on his criteria), including those recently added.

I can think of few teoretical aproaches such as views, materialized views, direct querying, precalculating using triggers to another table. Each of those have its impacts, positives, negatives. For example I can't even imagine refreshing materialized views.

Does anyone have experience with such tasks? Any insight is apprecitiated. Even infrastructure tips, third party tools, anything helpful. My biggest concern now is the software solution to create, not HW scaling.

Cheers.

Comment: At the rate of 200 records per second you will have 63 billion rows in 10 years time. In 10 years time are you really likely to care about transaction level granularity? At the very least you will need to use [partitioning](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-partitioning.html) to separate your data, 63 billion rows is unmanageable in a single partition. This way your partition size is going to be c.535m rows, which while still a lot, is going to be easier to manage than a single partition.

Comment: Next you want to consider an OLAP environment. If you are likely to need to report on a fairly high scale level then store the data in high level, combine this with your partitions, for instance, assuming your data is inserted chronologically, partition your data by month, then once a partition is complete (at the start of the next month), add summaries of your previous month to a warehouse. If you need up to the second accurate reporting you can combine queries from your warehouse to get historic data, and just your latest partition for the more recent data.

Comment: I agree, partitioning is a must. Dividing to recent and historical part was first idea we got. Now we are discussing possibilities of using Solr on top of our database and moving all the described reporting to Solr and simplyfiing database role to serve as plain storage providing source data for Solr. Unfortunately we don't have much experience with Solr like solutions yet.

Comment: Do you actually need to hold on to the individual transactions, or are you only interested in the aggregates? Could you get away with incrementally updating some precalculated aggregate value after each INSERT, and then throwing the underlying record away?

Comment: Yes I do. We have to be able to provide all details about any particular transaction at any time. Only a subset of all trx related information will be subject to aggregation.

Comment: Ok... There's something called [PipelineDB](http://docs.pipelinedb.com/introduction.html), based on Postgres, which handles continuous aggregation, though I can't tell you much else about it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll look into it. Never heard of that before.

Answer (score 0):

You should use partitioning for your table. Split your table into several tables, say, by month. [Partitioning](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/ddl-partitioning.html) is a private case of inheritance in Postgresql.